# "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" while reading csv file in python with nltk

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm doing pre-processing on this csv file but it didn't proceed - I got an error of `"TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"`:

[image: dataset image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import nltk

dataset =pd.read_csv('blogtext.csv')

seq=dataset.iloc[:,6]
```

the output would be a 7 column ofblogtext.csv file but I'm getting an error.

Comment: post a snapshot of the csv you are trying to read

Comment: kindly check it in description.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have float values in your dataset.

You need to convert these float values to string values.

Answer (score 0):

The "pandas.DataFrame.iloc" is Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position, .iloc[] is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.

For example ,

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
{'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
{'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

print(df.iloc[0])

'''
Output:
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
'''

df.iloc[[0]]

'''
Output
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
'''

df.iloc[[0, 1]]

'''
Output
     a    b    c    d
0    1    2    3    4
1  100  200  300  400
'''

df.iloc[:3]

'''
Output
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
'''
```